# NoHostAvailableException while reading in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

We are getting nohostavailable exception on client for reading 2000 rows( just 3 simple columns ), tried on different tables but ended up with same error. I changed socket connect and read timeout but still it didn't solve the issue.  And I found that even if i execute the query on cqlsh on node with tracing on, i am getting trace not complete in 10 seconds error(its showing up sometimes and clear other times) after displaying the rows. I see all nodes are up and running with mem and cpu in normal state. Any help on where i need to look to find the issue, will be very much appreciated. Thanks.   ( this is c2.1.5 open source )

Comment: can you post the trace?

Comment: Hi.. that is my issue . I cant get the trace .it says "Statement trace did not complete within 10 seconds".  i am assuming even at the client side it is showing no host available bcz of the same issue.